# Unexplainable/unclear write restrictions/error/exceptions in Windows Documents Folder

Tags: windows, permissions, documents, write-protect

When I use a commandline tool like `npm create vite` to create a React project in one of the subfolders or the `Documents` folder itself, then `npm` hangs up. However when I create project whereelse, like the `Desktop` folder of the user, then it works.

I had similar issues with other programs I wrote an compiled. I wrote and tested a simple `fwrite` program, just simply writing to file pointer, in C, and it always exited with `errno == 0x2` which is a `file not found exception`.

Suspicious is VSCode. After installing Fix Checksum, I had silence, but maybe it's not working properly and VSCode is corrupted, or its a bug.

It's interesting that when I use intellij and the `Documents` folder, a Desktop App with GUI seems to be able to create and delete files just fine. However using commandline tools like `npm` or my test program, with simple write operation, is not working.

I already checked restrictions of the `Documents` folder. My user has full rights to everything - write, read, execute, etc.

However it seems to be that there a program running in the background, blocking any write attemps by commandline executables.

Windows 10 is up-to-date.

Comment: Likely related to https://superuser.com/questions/1775234/how-to-have-an-app-be-trusted-by-windows-to-bypass-the-ransomeware-protection and similar questions